# Average a nested list in R

Tags: r, list, lapply, nested-lists, sapply

I have list similar to the below example

```
example <- list(
  list(A = 10, B = list(H = 110, E = 211, G = c(1.4,2)), C = c(13,24)),
  list(A = 15, B = list(H = 100, E = 201, G = c(0.1,5)), C = c(11,25)),
  list(A = 5,  B = list(H = 101, E = 221, G = c(1.2,3)), C = c(14,21))
)
```

The lists are identical in shape, and all numeric. I want to average them elementwise and save the mean in the same list of

```
list(A = . , B = list(H = . , E = . , G = c(.,.)), C = c(.,.)),
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write a simple one-liner recursive function that concatenates parallel members of two identically-structured lists, call `Reduce` on this function with your list as an operand, then `rapply` to get the mean:

```r
example <- list(
  list(A = 10, B = list(H = 110, E = 211, G = c(1.4,2)), C = c(13,24)),
  list(A = 15, B = list(H = 100, E = 201, G = c(0.1,5)), C = c(11,25)),
  list(A = 5,  B = list(H = 101, E = 221, G = c(1.2,3)), C = c(14,21))
)

f <- function(a, b) if(is.list(a)) Map(f, a, b) else rbind(a, b)
rapply(Reduce(f, example), colMeans, how = "list")
#> $A
#> [1] 10
#> 
#> $B
#> $B$H
#> [1] 103.6667
#> 
#> $B$E
#> [1] 211
#> 
#> $B$G
#> [1] 0.900000 3.333333
#> 
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] 12.66667 23.33333
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way, but not sure it is appropriate for your real problem.

```r
library(rlist) # to use list.unzip

example <- list(
  p1 = list(A = 10, B = list(H = 110, E = 211, G = c(1.4,2)), C = c(13,24)),
  p2 = list(A = 15, B = list(H = 100, E = 201, G = c(0.1,5)), C = c(11,25)),
  p3 = list(A = 5,  B = list(H = 101, E = 221, G = c(1.2,3)), C = c(14,21))
)

u <- list.unzip(example)
u$B <- apply(u$B, 1L, simplify2array)

Mean <- function(x) {
  if(is.matrix(x)) {
    rowMeans(x)
  } else {
    mean(x)
  }
}

rapply(u, Mean, how = "replace")
# $A
# [1] 10
# 
# $B
# $B$H
# [1] 103.6667
# 
# $B$E
# [1] 211
# 
# $B$G
# [1] 0.900000 3.333333
# 
# 
# $C
# [1] 12.66667 23.33333
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `rrapply()` (in package `rrapply`) to unnest the nested list into a wide data.frame, after which we can calculate means across columns of the data.frame. To transform the results back into a nested list, we can use `relist()` (if necessary).

```
library(rrapply)

## return single-layer list
(result <- rrapply(example, how = "bind") |>
  apply(2, \(x) Reduce("+", x) / length(x)))
#> $A
#> [1] 10
#> 
#> $B.H
#> [1] 103.6667
#> 
#> $B.E
#> [1] 211
#> 
#> $B.G
#> [1] 0.900000 3.333333
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] 12.66667 23.33333

## return nested list
relist(unlist(result), skeleton = example[[1]])
#> $A
#> [1] 10
#> 
#> $B
#> $B$H
#> [1] 103.6667
#> 
#> $B$E
#> [1] 211
#> 
#> $B$G
#> [1] 0.900000 3.333333
#> 
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] 12.66667 23.33333
```